# Temperature Differences on Satallites

Tags: nuclear, temperature

Some satellites have radioisotope thermal generators. To convert thermal energy to electricity, a temperature difference is required (such as when using a thermocouple). How is a temperature difference maintained on a satellite? It seems difficult to remove the heat from the satellite.

Comment: What satellites have RTGs?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Starting from Transit4A, back in july 1961? many!

Answer (score 2):

The RTG is usually at the end of a deployed boom.

This allows a hot:cold junction to be created by insulating the heat producing element except where the cold junction will be, and allowing that cold junction good visibility to space away from the spacecraft body.  In practice some (old) designs are cylindrical with the cold junction effectively around the heat producing element (i.e. only need for insulation is at the ends of the cylinder). The outer cylinder then has longitudinal vanes as these are an effective way to increase the thermal radiating surface, thus cooling the cold junction further.

The boom installation also allows a reduction in the coupling of radioactive decay products to the spacecraft systems.

Further reading: [Wikipedia - RTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator)
[image: Cassini RTG]

[image: New Horizons RTG]